# Form submit after populating checkbox through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am populating a group of checkboxes by below code

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/mySite/getOutletsByRegion?regionId='+str,
 success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, obj) {

        html +='<li><label><input id="outlet1" type="checkbox" value="'+obj.id+'" name="outlet"/>';
        html +=obj.name+"</label></li>";

        });
    $("#outlets").html(html);
 }
```

But when I am submitting this form , these newly created checkbox values are not available.
Am I missing some steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every ID and name of the new check boxes are the same but should be unique. You could use an array at least for the name attribute

```
html +='<li><label><input id="outlet' + i + '" type="checkbox" value="'+obj.id+'" name="outlet[' + i + ']"/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete the previouse answer, you need unique names for form submission, or you can use [] for array, like this:

```
html +='<li><label><input id="outlet1" type="checkbox" value="'+obj.id+'" name="outlet[]"/>';
html +=obj.name+"</label></li>";
```

Also I do not know what **"#outlets"** is make sure you are not injecting the elements AFTER your  tag, because it will not get submitted in that case